# Replacing HTML closing tags in sed

Tags: sed

I am writing a script which will read some data from txt files and then generate an html file with the data from the other files. I have lines starting with # which I have to skip - this is done. But the problem is that when I read the files I have to skip the words `<head>, </head>, <body> and </body>.`

I don't have problem with excluding  and , I am using:

```
cat ~/linux/footer.txt | sed 's/<head>//g' > ~/linux/footer_temp.txt
```

but the problem is with `</head> and </body>`...

Any suggestions what can I use and how to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your pattern has slashes in it, sed will let you use a different character as the delimiter, for example:

```
sed 's|</head>||g'
```

Comment: could you please check the issue i have explained in my next answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's#</?(head|body)>##g' file
```

or:

```
sed 's/<\/\?\(head\|body\)>//g' file
```

This uses the `#` for the substitution delimiter, `?` metacharacter to denote one one none (in this case `/`) and grouping and alternation to match either `head` or `body`.